# Why doesn't the pretrained model identify the cars?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I use TensorFlow YOLOV3 for object detection, I use the pretrained model by COCO dataset.

The model identify only the horizontal cars which turn to the left:

[image]

Why doesn't the model identify the rest of the cars?

Comment: It depends on several factors. The quality of the trained model, some threshold after which an object is recognized as car or not. Maybe the orientation plays a role as well (but you can flip your image left to right to test that). Without code, its hard to guess.